# Spring Themes not working with REST

Tags: spring, rest, spring-mvc, themes, web.xml

I have been trying to solve this problem for several days now and I also couldn't find any posts in forums with a similar problem. I have Spring Theme working well when I have the servlet mapping url-pattern as *.html in the web.xml file. However, if I change the url-pattern in the web.xml file to forward slash, so that the default servlet handles all requests and that the URLs can look like REST URLs, then I use to get NO MAPPING error, which results in not able to display the css settings for web pages.  The NO MAPPING warning that I get use to get is as follows:

```
WARN http-apr-8080-exec-6 (DispatcherServlet.java:947) - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/MyApp/themes/default.css] in DispatcherServlet with name 'spring'.
```

But upon the mapping issue being solved by adding to my Spring servlet configuration file:

```
<mvc:default-servlet-handler />
```

another problem has arisen: **Now**, upon the application being started and prior to any operations, the use of clicking the Theme choice prior to any REST operation works well.  It all works fine displaying the correct Theme.  In fact, if I go via the normal Controllers (without REST) and do non-REST operations, everything continues to work as normal and I can switch between Themes.  *However*, upon going via REST, and upon clicking on a Theme and even though it returns the same *view* name as the normal Controller would return, I get the following error in the browser and strangely with no console (debug) messages being reported:

```
    HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported

    type Status report

    message Request method 'GET' not supported

    description The specified HTTP method is not allowed for the requested resource (Request method 'GET' not supported).


    Apache Tomcat/7.0.29
```

Here is my **UPDATED** web.xml files is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
      <display-name>LiveAppSpring</display-name>
      <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
      </welcome-file-list>
      <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
      </context-param>
      <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
      </listener>
      <filter>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>encoding</param-name>
          <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
          <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
      </filter>
      <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      </filter-mapping>
      <servlet>
        <servlet-name>liveAppSpring</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
          <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
          <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
      </servlet>
      <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>liveAppSpring</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
      </servlet-mapping>
    </web-app>
```

and my **UPDATED** Spring servlet configuration is:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans:beans xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
                 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                 xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
                 xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
                 xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
                 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">


        <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

        <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->

        <mvc:annotation-driven />

        <mvc:default-servlet-handler />

        <mvc:interceptors>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
            </beans:bean>
            <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
                <beans:property name="paramName" value="theme" />
            </beans:bean>                      
        </mvc:interceptors>


        <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

        <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
        <!--  
        <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        View Classes:
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />
        -->
        <!--  
        <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
            <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />       
            <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
            <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
        </beans:bean>

        -->

        <!-- This attribute could also be added to viewResolver bean below... 
        <beans:property name="requestContextAttribute" value="requestContext"/>
         -->
        <beans:bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">        
            <beans:property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesView" />       
        </beans:bean>   


        <beans:bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles2.TilesConfigurer">
            <beans:property name="definitions">
                <beans:list>
                    <beans:value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</beans:value>
                </beans:list>
            </beans:property>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Application Message Bundle -->
        <beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
            <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
            <beans:property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
            <beans:property name="defaultLocale" value="en"/>
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- Theme setup -->
        <beans:bean id="themeSource" class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
                <beans:property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
        </beans:bean>

        <beans:bean id="themeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
            <beans:property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
        </beans:bean>

        <!-- 
           The 2 bean declarations below are NOT compatible with 3.0.5 as it conflicts with the mvc tag library (as defined in header).
           Work around is to have the mvc:interceptors tag declared as done near the top of this configuration file.
        -->

        <!--  
        <beans:bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
            <beans:property name="paramName" value="lang" />
        </beans:bean>
        -->

        <!--   
        <beans:bean id="handlerMapping" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping">     

            <beans:property name="interceptors">
                <beans:ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
            </beans:property>

        </beans:bean>
        -->

        <context:component-scan base-package="com.liveapp.spring" />

    </beans:beans>
```

And finally, my Theme properties files are location in

```
LiveAppSpring\src\main\resources
```

with the contents of all Theme properties files having the following pattern:

```
css=themes/default.css
```

AND to be safe, I have my css files duplicated in all 3 directories:

```
LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\resources

LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\resources\themes 

LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\themes
```

Any directions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the relevant parts of your configuration (web.xml, spring configuration (Theme Resolver, Resource Mapping))

Comment: Post the configuration. My guess is you are missing either a resource mapping or don't have the `<mvc:default-servlet-handler />` element in your configuration.

Comment: Sure.  Here is my web.xml :

Comment: @Ralph I have added web.xml and spring configuration.

Comment: @M.Deinum I have added web.xml and spring configuration to my original post.

Comment: @M.Deinum Thanks for your tip to add <mvc:default-servlet-handler />, which solved the mapping problem, but has arisen another problem.  Please see the summary of my updated problem in my comment to Ralph below or for a detailed description, please review my updated post above.

Comment: Can you add the @Controller...

Comment: I already have the @Controller annotated above my REST Controller class.  My REST application works in business logic, but my problem is that the selected Theme is lost when going via REST and when I click on one of the Theme links to change the Theme, then I get the _HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported_ browser error message. Note, as stated before, I do not have this problem if I use the normal Spring Controllers.  Any other suggestions?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that `/MyApp/themes/default.css` should deliver `default.css`. But this is a resource file, and you mapped them by

```
 <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
```

So the right request url would be `/MyApp/resources/default.css` (assuming that the `default.css` is located in `webapp/resources/default.css`)

Comment: Hi Ralph, I have updated yet again my web.xml & Spring servlet configuration files, with a new problem arising, that is, now I get __HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported__.  Do note that if I go via non-REST controllers everything works fine and I can dynamically change between Themes, however, upon going via REST Controller and even though it is return the exact same view name as the normal Controller, I get the above browser error, but strangely with no console (debug) messages being displayed.

Comment: Please refer to my updated Post above for more details regarding this new problem.  Thanks.

Comment: I forgot to mention that my Theme .properties files are location in LiveAppSpring\src\main\resources **AND** my css files are duplicated in both LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\resources & LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\themes directories.  And still I get the **HTTP Status 405 - Request method 'GET' not supported** browser error message. Any ideas or do you think this could be a bug with core Spring MVC?

Comment: And finally, I have also duplicated my .css files into directory _LiveAppSpring\src\main\webapp\resources\themes_ in addition to the ones mentioned above.

Comment: Does this HTTP405 occure when you request for `/MyApp/themes/default.css` ?

Comment: No.  The default.css file comes up in Notepad.

Comment: No, unfortunately it's not.  However, there is a slight twist.  I have just now added extra REST methods to support GET and PUT in addition to the existing POST and strangely, the HTTP Status 405 message has disappeared, but still the selected css file does not get loaded even though I can access the css file directly via the browser (as suggested). By the way, in the generated HTML code it does have a reference to css like this: <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/black.css" type="text/css"/>, but still the css file does not load up.  Could it be something to do with a bug in Spring MVC core?

Comment: I highly doubt that the problem is a bug in Spring, I expect is the bug in your application.

Comment: The href links should start with an `/` followed by the application name: `/MyApp/themes/black.css`

Comment: Thanks Ralph that did the trick!  But how come it worked with just themes/black.css at the application start up and when using just normal Spring Controller prior to REST? And also, if you have time, could you answer these 2 short questions: Q1. I added _<mvc:default-servlet-handler />_ annotation to the Spring servlet config file, will this impose any restrictions in my future Spring application development? Q2. My normal Spring Controller works well, but after I invoking REST Controller, I can NOT re-invoke the normal Spring Controller methods and I get HTTP Status 400 error. Is this normal?

Comment: without the leading `/` the href target depends on your current url, so the result is depending on which page you "are". Q1: I expect no problems, but if you get any later on you can still replace it with an explicite configuration. Q2: no -- ask this in a new question. With all the needed details, as well as the controller two Methods and an example which shows in wich order you invoke which url, what the result is, and if there is any exception then post it too.

Comment: Hi Ralph, thanks again for your help in which I tried to solve this problem for several days and had 2 sleepless nights!  I attempted to Vote Up for your answer, but I get a message from this site saying that a vote requires 15 recommendations.  As I am a new member, I only have one recommendation, so my sincere apologises that I can't vote.